# Extract number as an an integer from a string

Tags: excel

I have some data which is badly formatted ( inherited) after some manipulation and some concatenation I have  something resembling the following in a string

"SIGNAGE -- 11 Requires door signage. "

My table has to cross reference a some data from a VLOOKUP and then tries to get the first chars in a pattern after the --

My formula is this

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($C3,DoorCheck!$D3:$AD79,19,FALSE)<>"",LEFT((RIGHT((VLOOKUP($C3,DoorCheck!$D3:$AD79,19,FALSE)), LEN((VLOOKUP($C3,DoorCheck!$D3:$AD79,19,FALSE)))-SEARCH("--", (VLOOKUP($C3,DoorCheck!$D3:$AD79,19,FALSE)),1)-2)),2),"")
```

This successfully gives me the number 11.

My problem is that the number is being treated as a string and not as a numeric value.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NUMBERVALUE()` function to convert a string into a number.

Answer (score 1):

I often use the trick when getting numbers out of text with LEFT(), MID() or RIGHT() to do a "*1" as the final step.

```
=mid(....) *1
```

for example,

So, yours would be :

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($C3,DoorCheck!$D3:$AD79,19,FALSE)<>"",LEFT((RIGHT((VLOOKUP($C3,DoorCheck!$D3:$AD79,19,FALSE)), LEN((VLOOKUP($C3,DoorCheck!$D3:$AD79,19,FALSE)))-SEARCH("--", (VLOOKUP($C3,DoorCheck!$D3:$AD79,19,FALSE)),1)-2)),2),"")*1
```